# Fiddler Shows crossed out text on capturing the traffic

Tags: telerik, fiddler, webapi

[Crossed out capture on fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4NHp.png)

The Fiddler captures the traffic, but crosses out the text or captures. Please see the image for more details. Hoe do i get rid of this/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `Help -> Troubleshoot` option is enabled. If this is the case, the traffic which is normally filtered by the filters applied in the Filters tab is shown with strikethrough font.

From the screenshot, it seems that all or most of the traffic is filtered - you can uncheck the 'Use filters' check box in the Filters tab to disable the filters.

Comment: The fiddler fails to capture the traffic if I uncheck the Troubleshoot. I dont know why:(

Comment: It's most probably because of some applied filters. Filters can be applied in the Filters tab, or in the grey pane below the session list (where they can be removed by right click).